# Watch URL changes in Firefox

Tags: web-browser, firefox

I'm looking for `Firefox` extension that is able to watch for changes on a particular
webpage, similar to command line application [urlwatch](https://thp.io/2008/urlwatch/).

It should be able to watch

1. large number of webpages (not limited by a small number e.g. 20)
2. partial content on a webpage
3. give little false positives
4. it should be free

Comment: will [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pageprobe/) do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I have used several different Firefox extensions that will accomplish your goals.  The best one I have found is **Update Scanner** by sneakypete81.  It is available here:

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/update-scanner/

It is gratis (free of charge), and like all extensions, is open-source.  I never had any issues with false positives.

However good it was, it was not flexible enough for my use.  I continued to search for tools, and I eventually found **WebChangeMonitor**.  It's not a web browser extension, but it is so much better than all the web browser extensions I tried.  It is a portable standalone software for Linux and Windows.  It is available here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/webchangemon/

WebChangeMonitor is also gratis and open-source.  It is very flexible, and will do exactly what you want.  You can configure it to eliminate just about any false positive as well as detect changes in a specified section of any page.  I highly recommend it.